# How to upgrade Tomcat version in existing Hybris system implemented in cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Helo everyone ,
Currently my application is running on Hybris version 18.08 with  tomcat of version 8.5.23
Due to some vulnerability reasons we need to upgrade the tomcat version to 8.5.72.
My application is built on google cloud platform and we used terraform to built the structure.
I found few docs in the google to do this https://help.sap.com/viewer/a74589c3a81a4a95bf51d87258c0ab15/1808/en-US/5f704237175a44c7ab4cd9ec7cc7293d.html

this suggest to delete the directories directly but I my system is based out of terraform and all the vm instances created are done via that , so can anyone let me know how to initiate this
Waiting for response

Answer (score 0):

Hybris Upgrades the tomcat version with their new releases so upgrading the hybris version altogether could be one of the options, else you have the right link how hybris suggest.